# JavaScript - calling a function with variable in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with features, and I want to call a function with variables when i click the map.

```
  window.addEventListener("map:init", function (event) {
    var map = event.detail.map;
    // Download GeoJSON data with Ajax
    fetch(dataurl)
      .then(function(resp) {
        return resp.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
          L.geoJson(data, {
              onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                  var props = feature.properties;
                  var x = props.confirmed.split(',');
                  var y = props.delta_days.split(',');
              }
          }).addTo(map).on('click', function(e) {
              plotter(x, y);
          });
      });
  });
```

I  am  new to js and this is what I came up with, but it obviously does not work because x,y are variables inside a loop. So when the function gets called x and y are no longer defined.

Any ideas how to do it ? the function I am calling is a plotly function that plots a simple graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read out the x and y from the clicked marker.

You can use 2 ways:

**1. Read out the feature properties**

```
.addTo(map).on('click', function(e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    var props = layer.feature.properties;
    var x = props.confirmed.split(',');
    var y = props.delta_days.split(',');    
    plotter(x, y);
})
```

**2. Add the vars to the layer**

```
L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        var props = feature.properties;
        var x = props.confirmed.split(',');
        var y = props.delta_days.split(',');
        layer.x = x;
        layer.y = y;
    }
}).addTo(map).on('click', function(e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    plotter(layer.x, layer.y);
});
```